# What is the origins of the phrase “on the lam”?

Tags: phrase-meaning

After puzzling over this phrase for quite some time I came across the possible answers offered in this site.  The one that seemed to show the most promising solution was the longest entry, which included the possibility of there being a verb “to lam” meaning “to run.” I found just such a verb in the *English Dialect Dictionary*, a somewhat now forgotten, yet very useful, text.  I here provide the germane entry, from Vol. III, pp. 509-10:

> “LAM...4. to run quickly. w. Yks 5 Whear’s tuh lamming tul! Ther wur a
> peeler after him - by Gow didn’t he lam!”

The above quotation - which seems to fit exactly the meaning of “lam” - as “running from the police” (i.e. a “peeler”) - comes from C.C Robinson’s  *The Dialect of Leeds and its Neighbourhood*, of 1861.

Comment: @user66974 Having followed your link I did begin to wonder whether 'lam' meaning to run was related to 'lam' meaning to beat via the phrase 'hit the road' or even 'hit the ground running', although I suspect that the latter is of later coinage.

Comment: From the little work I’ve devoted to this, I can see that the “lam” means “beat” link is very prevalent and well documented.  With my dialectical information, however, I attempt to skip any extra steps altogether. With the  “beat” meaning one must somehow attempt to “reverse” this definition  to one where a person tries to avoid a beating by running away from it. With the definition I provide, and with the aid of Occam’s Razor, one need not switch or reverse anything because “lam” means “run.”

Comment: I take it you looked here: [link](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=lam)

Comment: Yes, i have seen that, but as the definition I provide predates most of that formation and because it makes a direct connection between “lam” and “run” I stopped looking.